# WordPress multi-site in a subfolder on host

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering about a WordPress multi-site installation and nothing I've come across has clearly laid this out for me. I'm hoping to get a little more clarification on what exactly will happen in my WordPress/Server instance if I set up a multi-site.

I've currently got my actual site as a single instance Wordpress install at the root of my domain. I'd like to keep it that way.

I've set up a sub-folder on my site called "client-login" and it has it's own WordPress install. The idea is to make this WordPress instance a multi-site one. With the intent being that I can have multiple sites in there and give access to them as needed.

So far it all is making sense but when I go to actually complete the multi-site install it says the server address will be my domain at root level. It doesn't say domain/client-login.

My question is if I turn on the multisite will it take over the root of my domain and include my "real" site as part of it?

Comment: multisite will create sites with the base of the root domain, it wont create a subfolder outside the root

Comment: @charankumar so are you confirming that If i set up a multi-site it wouldn't respond to my domain/client-login. It would instead be right at the root?

Comment: untill unless if you wont create a subsite with name client-login, it will stay inside the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets consider,

you have a main wordpress domain at public_html/

you have created a subfolder in host like public_html/client-login for another wordpress instance

these two will behave as a separate sites.

The wordpress multisite will work inside the public_html/mainsite not outside of it, and it wont affect the client-login subfolder.

Comment: Ah ok thats for clarification! So it will behave the opposite of how I want it to then - good to know